# Customizing named route in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a resourceful route on a resource member, but I can't seem to find the syntax to create the named route that I want.

```
namespace :admin
  resources :foobars do
    get :attribute, on: :member, as: :attribute
  end
end
```

This will provide a route method called:

```
attribute_admin_foobar_path
```

I would like it to say:

```
admin_foobar_attribute_path
```

The only other way I can think of would be to reject the `resources` block and create a single route:

```
namespace :admin
  resources :foobars
  get 'foobars/:id/attribute', as: :foobar_attribute
end
```

However, I don't like this approach because it forces me to duplicate the routing structure of already existing routes...not very DRY.

Is there a way that I can create the route name that I want while still using the `resources` routing block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it like this:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :foobars do
      get :attribute
    end
  end
```

You will get:

```
admin_foobar_attribute GET /admin/foobars/:foobar_id/attribute(.:format)                    admin/foobars#attribute
```

That is `admin_foobar_attribute_path`.

Comment: hmm...that's better, but then the param is changed to `foobar_id` instead of `id`

Comment: I decided to just go with it. I like the minimal syntax. So I updated my code to be flexible enough to handle both scenarios: `Foobar.find(params[:id] || params[:foobar_id])`